# How to pass arguments from e.g script.ps1 to mainScript.ps1 in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a problem with passing arguments from one script to another.
I just want to use those arguments in my main function. I used to write something like that e.g Write-Host "pls give path..." and then my argument was like this e.g $SourceCopyFolder = Read-Host. Unfortunately i do not know how to do this while having two separate scripts... :(

I have argScript.ps1 with arguments:

```
PARAM
(
  [String] $SourceCopyFolder = "C:\abcd",
  [String] $DestinationCopyFolder  = "C:\qwerty",
  [String] $LogFileDestination  = "C:\logfile.log"
) #end param
```

And mainScript.ps1

```
Functon CopyFilesScript($SourceCopyFolder, $DestinationCopyFolder, $LogFileDestination)
{   
     Write-Host "Your source folder" $SourceCopyFolder -ForegroundColor Green

     If(Test-Path $Path\*.zip)
     { 
        $Shell = New-Object -com Shell.Application
        $Location = $Shell.NameSpace($SourceCopyFolder)
        $Filename = Get-Childitem $Path -Recurse -Include *.ZIP
        $progress = 1

        foreach ($ZipFile in $Filename)
        {
            Write-Progress -Activity "Unzipping to $($SourceCopyFolder)" -PercentComplete (($progress / ($Filename.Count + 1)) * 100) -CurrentOperation $ZipFile.FullName -Status "File $($Progress) of $($Filename.Count)"
            $Destination = $Shell.NameSpace($ZipFile.fullname)
            $Location.Copyhere($Destination.items(), 1040)
            $progress++
        }
  }
        Write-Host "Your source folder from which you want to copy files" $SourceCopyFolder -ForegroundColor Green
        Write-Host ""
        Write-Host "Your destination folder where you want to paste files" $DestinationCopyFolder -ForegroundColor Green
        Write-Host ""
        Write-Host "Your path to save Log file" $LogFileDestination -ForegroundColor Green

        Robocopy $SourceCopyFolder $DestinationCopyFolder /e /xf *.zip /LOG+:$LogFileDestination ###xf - exclude files with .zip extension
}
```

Can somebody help me understand how to solve this? Thanks for all answers

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. How are you running `mainScript.ps1` currently?

Comment: I was using a previous version of that, which was just a script without a function. Now i have to make a script with function and it should use parameters from seconde script :) because i want to make it more automatically without Write and Read-Host's in my function code

Comment: That doesn't really explain anything and doesn't show what you are trying that isn't working. Did you try anything? Calling/sourcing the script will just define the function. You need to call the function too.

Comment: I tried to do it like in answer, it's calling my function but I get an error "'CopyFilesScript' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program." I am beginner in powershell so maybe i just can't understand your point of view :/

Comment: How did you load/run `mainScript.ps1`?

Comment: by putting. "
. "c:\users\abcd\Documents\mainScript.ps1" " into argScript.ps1 I think it's function call am I right?

Comment: That should load that script into the current script's context, yes. That should let `argScript.ps1` see the function from `mainScript.ps1`.

Comment: The code in your question for `CopyFilesScript` has a typo ("Functon" instead of "Function") - is there any chance that typo is in your actual script? That might explain the error "'CopyFilesScript' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program."

Comment: Yeah I noticed that 3 days ago and now it works :) but thanks for your answer